# Is there anything that cannot appear inside parentheses?

Tags: python, vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I was intrigued by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542929/highlighting-unmatched-brackets-in-vim/543881#543881) to my question about [getting vim to highlight unmatched brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542929/highlighting-unmatched-brackets-in-vim) in python code.  Specifically, I'm talking about the second part of his answer where he mentions that the C syntax highlighting is actually flagging as an error any instance of curly braces inside parens.  It is an unobtrusive cue that you have unclosed parens when all of your downstream curly braces light up in red.

That trick works because C syntax doesn't allow curly braces inside parentheses.  To satisfy my (morbid?) curiosity, can I do something similar with python code?  Is there anything in python syntax that isn't legal inside parentheses?

Note: I'm not trolling for a better answer to my other question (there are plenty of good answers there already).  I'm merely curious if this trick is even possible with python code.

Comment: @Kristo: What you wrote makes very little sense.  The answer is trivially obvious; so why would you ask it?  Most people ask questions because they can't do something.  What can't you do?  What problem do you have?  "merely curious" seems silly; there's usually more.

Comment: The answer wasn't trivially obvious to me.  I'm sorry if I caused you confusion.  Anyway, I've learned something new from this question so I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any Python statement (import, if, for, while, def, class etc.) cannot be in the parentheses:

```
In [1]: (import sys)
------------------------------------------------------------
File "<ipython console>", line 1
  (import sys)
       ^
<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Does this include the default if-else?  a = b if c else d?

Comment: the "b if c else d" can be in ()s because it's an expression. The assignment part ("a = ...") cannot, because in Python assignment is a statement. In Python, no statement can be in parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an exact answer:

- http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression_list
- http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but how about "def" or "class"?

this snippet is valid when it's not inside parenthesis

```
class dummy: pass
```

Comment: No Statement can be ()'d  Only expressions.