# Adding custom highlighting for project's API function names in Vim

Tags: vim

How can I add new function names for .c and .h files to be highlighted, similar to this 
                 [Customizing Syntax Highlighting in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464593/custumizing-syntax-highlighting-in-vim) but much easier? (as I don't need to color words in 
                 different colors, only in the default color for keywords as defined by my theme).

I need this to add highlighting for function names in a project written in C which has a clearly defined API.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting this in `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`:

```
syn keyword Keyword func_name1 func_name2 func_name3
```

you can see the defined highlight groups with:

```
:highlight
```

if you want to pick your colors:

```
syn keyword Myfunctions func_name1 func_name2
highlight Myfunctions guifg=red
```

assuming you use the GUI version and you like red, check `:help highlight` for details.

If you want to keep this particular highlight local to a project instead of applying it to every C file, you can add this to your `.vimrc`

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *my_project/* source ~/.vim/myproject_syntax.vim
```

of course the path and the name and location of the syntax file are totally free.

Comment: You could also use an autocmd+function to apply them only to files within the path for that project, if it matters.

Comment: Er, or you could not get carried away, and just use an if within the ftplugin.

Comment: "an if" please elaborate on that

Comment: What are other names like "Keyword" (capital K), and how to define my own color?

Comment: Great. Someone said it's better to put it in `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`. Please update your answer and I'll be glad to accept it. Thanks