# Getting better syntax highlighting with ctags and vim

Tags: java, vim, ctags

I'm trying to set up vim to work nicely with Java. I've set up eclim, which seems to work great for letting me know when something is wrong, but I'd really like to get vim to do two things to make my code easier to read.

1. Have brackets and braces show up with a different colour from the main font.
2. Get classes to highlight as a different colour.

I haven't come up with anything good for the first point, but it seems like the second should be doable with ctags. I found a plugin called TagHilight that should do this but I can't seem to get it to work.

I also found a file called javaid.vim that is supposed to do this, but again I've had no luck with that.

Comment: I should note I'm using the latest version of Vim, and have ctags version 5.8.

Comment: I have no practical answer for you but you need to know one thing: Vim doesn't use ctags for syntax highlighting at all. It uses a regexp-based language-specific syntax file that contains all the keyword definition patterns used in turn by Vim for highlighting keywords. If such an "advanced" syntax file doesn't exist you will have to make one yourself, eventually starting with the default `java.vim` and/or `javaid.vim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first requirement of highlighting braces and brackets, there is no default highlight group for braces. You need to create one for yourself. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199267/braces-and-operators-coloring-in-vim-for-c) is how you do it!

For your second requirement of how to highlight classes, you should be using this `TagHighlight` [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2646). And [this](http://www.cgtk.co.uk/vim-scripts/taghighlight) page explains in detail about the plugin and how to get it working. It also shows you snapshots where your exact requirement is met! :)